# How can I add shortcut to StyleBox

Tags: front-end, customization, style, keyboard

How can I add shortcut to `StyleBox`?. We can <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd> to overstrike **font.**

**i.e. **strong** or `**strike**`.**

Can I add one new shortcut <kbd>Ctrl+R</kbd> to make the font become $\color{red}{Red}$?

Because they both are `Style/StyleBox`

`StyleBox["Bold", FontWeight->"Bold"]`

`StyleBox["Red", FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]`

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209405/customizing-mathematica-shortcuts) may be helpful. Next step is to modify  current selection.